# Can I approximate with a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normality-assumption, approximation

I feel like I should know this (I graduated in physics a couple of years ago), but I'm really unsure about whether or not it's appropriate to use a normal distribution for the following case:

I have two independent random quantities $X$ and $Y$. Both follow a hypergeometric probability distribution with $\text{Var}(X) \approx \text{Var}(Y)$ but $\text{E}(X)>\text{E}(Y)$.

I then construct an intermediate quantity $Z=X-Y$ and I know that $\text{E}(Z)=\text{E}(X)-\text{E}(Y)$ and $\text{Var}(Z)\approx 2\text{Var}(X)$.

Now I repeat this process $k$ times (each round is independent from the previous one) and sum up all the differences I get to the value I'm actually interested in: $D=\sum_i Z_i$. Again I'm pretty sure that $\text{E}(D)=k\text{E}(Z)$ and $\text{Var}(D)=k\text{Var}(Z)$.

However, for my application I need the probability $P(D\ge t)$ of the difference being at least some threshold value $t$, so I need the full shape of the probability distribution of $D$. Can I assume (for sufficiently large $k$), that $D$ follows a normal distribution with the above expected value and variance or do I need some other conditions (e.g. "only if you can approximate the distribution of $X$ by a binomial distribution") fulfilled? (Bonus question: How big does $k$ need to be?)

If I can not approximate it, does the convolution of a hypergeometric distribution with itself yield something nice? Are there any ressources for that? The few papers I found googling dealing with that were for far more general cases than I need and it seems not exactly trivial melting the full formula down to my special case.

Comment: The key to these questions is "how big does $k$ need to be." The answer to that depends on the parameters of the hypergeometric distributions of $X$ and $Y;$ so, what can you tell us about them?

Comment: @whuber Using the Wikipedia definition (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), I have $N\approx 1000n$ and $K$ is different for different setups (but constant within one $D$) and can be between $N/1000$ and $0.7N$. The difference between $X$ and $Y$ is that $N$ and $n$ for $X$ are 1 lower than for $Y$ and the $X$-distribution is shifted to the right by 1. Basically $X$ is the same as $Y$ except that one "hit" is already preselected.